# Non linear fit in r

Tags: r, nls

My data consist of two columns - time and cumulative number like below:

```
time <- c(1:14)
cum.num <- c(20, 45, 99, 195, 301, 407, 501, 582, 679, 753, 790, 861, 1011, 1441)
```

My non linear function is:

```
B/(B*C*exp(-A*B*time) + 1)
```

My objective is to model my data using non linear method. I tried the following:

```
m1 < -nls(cum.num ~ B/((B*C)*exp(-A*B*time) + 1)
```

I have tried several initial values but got the following error:

```
Error in nls(cum.vul ~ B/((B * C) * exp(-A * B * time) + 1), 
start = list(B = 60,  : singular gradient
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens you generally have to do a bit of detective work to understand the parameters of your function and get a rough estimate of the values by looking at plots.

```
time <- c(1:14)
cum.num <- c(20, 45, 99, 195, 301, 407, 501, 582, 679,
           753, 790, 861, 1011, 1441)
```

- The first thing to notice is that the top-level structure of the function is hyperbolic (i.e., of the form `1/(1+x)`). It will be easier to visualize the data and estimate parameters if we invert the `y` value, so that we have `1/cum.num ~ C*exp(-A*B*time) + 1/B`.

```
plot(time,1/cum.num,log="y",xlim=c(0,14),ylim=c(0.0005,0.5))
```

(plotting on a log-y scale, and extending the y-axis limits, based on what I discovered below ...)

[image]

- From the equation above, we know that the asymptote (value for large y) should be 1/B, so we have `1/B ~ 0.001` or `B ~ 1000`.
- at time 0, the value should be `C + 1/B = C + 0.001`.  Looking at the graph, we have `C ~ 0.5`
- Finally, `1/(A*B)` is the characteristic scale of decrease (i.e. the time for an e-fold decrease). It looks like the e-folding time ~ 1 (from t=1 to t=2) so `1/(A*B) ~ 1` so `A ~ 0.001`

Use these starting values to fit:

```
m1 <- nls(cum.num ~ B/((B*C)*exp(-A*B*time) + 1),
                   start=list(A=0.001,B=1000,C=0.5))
```

Seems to work.  Plot the predicted values:

```
tpred <- seq(0,14,length=101)
cpred <- predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(time=tpred))
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(time,cum.num)
lines(tpred,cpred)
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. if i want to compute the confidence interval of this model, still it sows error like this :Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in prof$getProfile() : singular gradient.........could you please clarify in this regard @Ben Bolker